# Force TextBox value from V to VM programmatically?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

Two-way binding works excellent, but in case of TextBox it happens when control loses focus.

In my case I have simple UI with 1 TextBox and Submit/Cancel buttons.

Submit button set as Default on a view. So, user can type text into textbox and hit "Enter" which will invoke Submit's command. This is good, but I need to access value from TextBox and it's not in VM because TextBox didn't loose focus. How do I force this binging to update from my code?

```
<TextBox
    Text="{Binding Comment, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Grid.Row="2"/>

<StackPanel
    Grid.Row="3"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button 
        Padding="20,5"
        Margin="5"
        Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
        Content="Cancel" IsCancel="True" />
    <Button 
        Padding="20,5"
        Margin="5"
        Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
        Content="Submit" IsDefault="True" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: There has been a question about handling this szenario before, problem is finding it...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on your TextBox binding.

Answer (score 1):

UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged will cause the source to be updated on every keystroke. This is the easiest approach.  If you do not want or need to have the source updated so frequently, you could also force an update by doing this code:

```
        BindingExpression expression = TextBoxDescription.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        expression.UpdateSource();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the VM not after every key press, but after the Submit-Button was pressed, you could use a BindingGroup on the View. Then in your Command handler, you'd first call BindingGroup.Commit and then a submit method on the VM. This doesn't work nicely with the usual VM RelayCommand, but you can create something I call a Sticky Command, in order to encapsulate this functionality.

A sticky command is a small component that is attached to the View in XAML through an attached property, registers a command handler, and is configured so that it calls a method on the VM using reflection. If you like, you can read up on it on http://wpfglue.wordpress.com .